# Auto permission clicker android

Tags: android, security, permissions

Is it possible to make a click on  allow button in android 6.0 while getting permission of user? My aim is not to wait for user response. If possible then how?

My idea is liked that: After getting a pop up window I want to check if it is a permission window. If yes then I would  like to make a click on the allow button. I need this due to my research purpose only.

Thanks  in advance. :)

Comment: Then whats the point of permission request in android ?? Its entirely dependent on users perspective to grant permission or not, which is not to be decided by application

Answer (score 0):

No that would be super obvious security vulnerability. You don't handle that pop up windows, it's handled by android and it's standard. You can't change or interact with it.

Comment: Can I control the touch? If yes then why not?

Comment: Just can you clarify how is that not an answer?  Is it possible to make a click on allow button in android 6.0 while getting permission of user? The question ... my answer ... No